# Can I discard and re-upload same version of unpublished APK uploaded to playstore?

Tags: android, release-management, google-play-console

I want to remove uploaded APK which was mistakenly uploaded for direct release (Unpublished still) and instead I want to use the same APK without version code change for Beta testing first and rollout the APK only after beta testing.

There is a button called discard at the bottom of release page, if I discard this APK, can I upload the same APK without VersionCode change for beta testing and proceed to actual release? please suggest.

Comment: It should have an option to Move to Beta can you check?

Comment: I could not find such option..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need not only to discard the release, but also delete the artifact from the Bundle Explorer. Then you should be able to re-upload the same APK in a different track.

Comment: would you please explain how to delete the artifact from the Artifact Library? where to find the Artifact Library? thank you.

Comment: The page is now called "App bundle explorer". If the APK/AAB has not been published in any track and is not part of any release, then you will have a button "Delete APK/AAB" in the bundle explorer for the given artifact.